# can't access compute engine external ip

Tags: nginx, google-compute-engine

I set up a google compute engine instance and installed nginx and now nginx is listening on port 80. I have a static external ip assigned to my instance and I just can't access my external ip address.

Why does this have to be so difficult? All the tutorials just say:

> install nginx and go to your external ip and you should arrive at the nginx welcome screen

I set firewall rules for http/https but nothing is working. Here's some stuff to look at:

nginx server config:

```
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name example.com;
root /var/www/example.com;
index index.html;
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

screen shot of instance:
[image]

nginx running:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3490/nginx
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      3490/nginx
```

I'm trying to go to: `104.196.111.24` but it just says `safari failed to open the page`

running `ifconfig` returns this:

```
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:de:3f:fb:67  
          inet addr:172.18.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:ac:11:00:02  
          inet addr:172.17.0.2  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:acff:fe11:2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1460  Metric:1
          RX packets:3802 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2248 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:21591383 (20.5 MiB)  TX bytes:351275 (343.0 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:54 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:54 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:3568 (3.4 KiB)  TX bytes:3568 (3.4 KiB)
```

Comment: Full disclosure, I don't know anything about google's compute engine in particular. But have you tried checking the iptables ruleset on the host itself? It may be blocking incoming HTTP traffic.

Answer (score 3):

### Closed port 80

```
$ nmap -p80 104.196.111.24
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-03-09 16:25 CET
Nmap scan report for 24.111.196.104.bc.googleusercontent.com (104.196.111.24)
Host is up (0.14s latency).
PORT   STATE  SERVICE
80/tcp closed http
```

This leads to think there's something wrong in the firewall configuration, despite the "Allow http traffic" and "Allow https traffic" options that are checked on your screenshot. Now I don't know more about the firewall configuration of a GCE.

(NB Somewhat later: as of now, `nmap` reports the host is down.)

### About my initial post

My initial post, below, would apply to a `nginx` instance running on the real host. I have missed the fact that you're *actually running a Virtual Machine*, where it may be normal to have `nginx` listening to local addresses ('something else' on the host proxies the requests to the VM). However I don't understand why the internal IP address does not show up in your `ifconfig` output.

### Initial post content:

If I understand well, you have an nginx instance running on a server whose address is 104.196.111.24. And when you try to access this address in a web browser, you get an error.

So, I'm not absolutely sure this will work, but I notice your nginx instance is listening to port 80 on 0.0.0.0 (ipv4), what is a local address. [Wikipedia says about it:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0)

> In the Internet Protocol Version 4, the address 0.0.0.0 is a
>   non-routable meta-address used to designate an invalid, unknown or
>   non-applicable target.

Moreover:

> In the context of servers, 0.0.0.0 means "all IPv4 addresses on the
>   local machine".

So I think there's something to fix here, as `nginx` seems to be reachable only from local addresses on your server.

Moreover, if I set myself `nginx` to listen to port 80 on 0.0.0.0 for any of my websites, then browsing this site will return an error (like connexion has been reinitialized, not an error from `nginx`).

So, I would try to set `nginx` to listen to port 80 on the external address, like:

```
listen 104.196.111.24:80;
```

(and of course after that, check this is right with `nginx -t` and then reload nginx rules with `service nginx reload`).

EDIT: the additional information from `ifconfig` lets me think there's really something wrong (or not setup) in the network configuration but I can't explain it: the address of the network card (eth0, running) is 172.17.0.2, what belongs to some special IANA reserved range of addresses. I would expect 104.196.111.24 to show up in `ifconfig`'s output, but it does not. I don't even understand how you can ssh into 104.196.111.24 without having it setup. Anyway, I think `nginx` can't be reached from the outside as long as it's listening on 0.0.0.0, this has certainly to be fixed in order to solve the problem, which may be done by fixing the network configuration.

Comment: this isn't working, it's complaining that it can't bind to that address. any other ideas?

Comment: Hum, it sounds like there's something else (what could explain why it defaulted to 0.0.0.0). It would be interesting to have more informations about the network configuration (especially the output of `ifconfig` to be able to check the main interface to the outside is correctly setup).

Comment: I wonder if there's some sort of limitation on my account because it's a trial account...

Comment: No idea, but the output of `ifconfig` remains interesting.

Comment: I'll try that and get back to you

Comment: i updated the question with that info

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect the addition of informations from `ifconfig`.

Comment: How are your firewall rules looking in the developer console? You have added the http-server server tag to you server but in your default-allow-http firewall rule you have to say that it is open to the world.

Comment: If you were able to solve this, you can post the answer here for other community members who may be seeing this same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use a wildcard, and it will work

```
    listen *:80;
    listen *:443 ssl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're at wrong place.
Based on the ifconfig result looks like you are at **google cloud shell** and not **ssh into your instance shell**.
If you're at your instance shell,  ifconfig result will match with internal ip address shown in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Check the firewall rules for your project's VPC:

```
$ gcloud beta compute firewall-rules list
```

If port 80 TCP is not covered, you need to add it:

```
$ gcloud beta compute firewall-rules create default-allow-http80 \
> --direction ingress --action allow --source-ranges 0.0.0.0/0 
> --rules tcp:80
```